# Min width vs Max Width

Tags: css

I'm new to media queries and I have a question.

I made a Desktop version of the website first and now I decided to make responsive too.

I've read that in this case I shall use `max-width` but I'm not sure.

Could you tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: why not trying and see?

Comment: I tried and I want to know which is better practice, min-width did not work bt max did and I just want to make sure

Comment: *min-width did not work bt max did* --> so you have your answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max-width in a media query means the following:

All styles applied in that media query will run as long as 'screen' is below the max width, for example, max-width: 1200px, all CSS will be applied under 1200px.

Min-width is the opposite, all CSS wil run as long as 'screen' is above the min-width, for example, min-width: 1200px, all CSS will be applied above 1200px.

Comment: *to clarify, once the max width is reached, the CSS will still exist, just not be applied.

Comment: If I helped you, could you select my answer as the Accepted answer? :)

Comment: i will be able to di it in 3 mins